# Error retrieving json with php

Tags: php, json

I've some problem retrieving json information with a PHP.

I've created a simple php page that returns a json:

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'Simple title'
);
print json_encode($data);
```

And in another page I try to get that array as an object:

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json_output = json_decode($content, true); 

switch(json_last_error())
{
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
        break;
}
```

The problem is that there is an error with this approach: I receive a "JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX" because after "file_get_contents" function I have an unknown character at the beginning of the string.

If I copy/paste it on Notepad++ I didn't see:

```
{"title":"Simple title"}
```

but I see:

```
?{"title":"Simple title"}
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: A little update: if I use the php function "utf8_encode" on the returned string, there is this "**ï»¿**" at the beginning of the string... I don't know why ...

Comment: That's UTF-8 BOM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), you should delete it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure both your scripts have same encoding - and if it's UTF make sure they are without Byte Order Mark (BOM) at very begin of file.

Comment: Thank you! I converted my php file with Notepad++ and all works!
First time I hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
$content = trim(file_get_contents($url));
```

?

Also, it sounds as if there was a problem with the encoding within the PHP that `echo`s your JSON. Try setting proper (as in: `content-type`) headers and make sure that both files are UTF-8 encoded.

---

Also: What happens if you open `$url` in your browser? Do you see an "?"

Comment: Thank for your answer, but the problem still exists...
1) I tried with the "trim" function - no result
2) I added "header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');" - no result
3) I check my files: they are both UTF-8

Comment: I've also open my url in my browser, but there isn't any "?".

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure your page that does the `json_encode` has a stray `?`.  Look in there for a missing `>` in terms of `?>` and such.

Comment: I checked it, but I don't have the terminator like "?>": every php file begin with "<?php" and doesn't have any ending string to avoid this type of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Look through your PHP for a stray "?".

Comment: There isn't any "?" in my php code, it was the first thing I tried :)